# .Net standard version for .Net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

Googled a bit but couldn't find the .Net standard version for .Net core 2.2. Only version I got is,

[image]

Any hint please?

Comment: May be worth reading this to see if this provides any insight. There is some talk about backwards compatibility issues https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/833 In this the discuss .net standard 2.1 with .net core 2.1. I'm unsure what the support is with 2.2.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support It is a pity that you only read the table, but neglect all the explanation below the table.

Comment: Close voters either didn't properly read the question, or have absolutely no clue what this question is about. The close reason makes no sense at all here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can see in the table you have uploaded, .NET Standard 2.0 is the latest available and it is fully supported by .NET Core v2.0. As you can see in this release doc. section, .NET Standard 2.1 will be supporting .NET Core 3.0 and also .NET Core 2.2. For the whole page check [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/05/announcing-net-standard-2-1/).

[image: .NET Standard 2.1]

In my opinion, you can go with .NET Standard 2.0 if you do not deal with extreme things (I mean recently added parts of .NET Core). This can yield some errors but still worth the try.

Comment: `fully supoorts .NET Core v2.0` - I think it other way around. .NET Core 2.0 **supports/implements** .NET Standard.

Comment: @Fabio vice versa is applicable. But what you say makes more sense.